# Uglify with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a .js like this and i'm compacting it:

```
'use strict';
!(function () {
  var object = typeof exports != 'undefined' ? exports : this;
}());
```

When I use the Google Closure compiler I don't get any erros and the 'this' is referencing the window object.
But when I use the Uglify ( with mangle true or false ) it gets a undefined on the 'this' ( so the object is undefined and I receive the error ). Does anyone knows why?

Basically I can just change the this to window and it will work but my concern is about other codes, libs or something else that I'm uglyfing in the future.

Note: I'm using the grunt-contrib-uglify plugin with the options:
mangle: true, preserverComments: false, sourceMap: true

Comment: So what is the result after minification?

Comment: `typeof exports != 'undefined'` is bad. Make that strict with `!==`

Comment: @m59 what do you mean by "bad"? Any details?

Comment: @m59 it's not bad because the `typeof` operator will definitely return a string.

Comment: You guys are defending loose equality? I'm questioning everything I know about programming. Are you saying this is a rare time where it is "ok" just because it can't cause a problem in this case?

Comment: @m59 well it's bad if your Douglas Crockford I guess :) If you want to live by and advocate a stricter coding standard then by all means Live Long And Prosper, but the fact is that it won't make any difference in this case.

Comment: @m59 I do not defend anything. I'm asking the technical reason why you don't recommend using `!-` here. Any problems with it in *this particular case*? "it is "ok" just because it can't cause a problem in this case" --- it is OK for developer to make thoughtful decisions, not just follow dogmas (that don't have (or do they?) a valid technical reason)

Comment: I don't understand the obsession with `===` and `!==` In most cases I know (really really know), what types I'm comparing, so why should I add that extra `=` in the first place?

Comment: @mmgross (disclaimer: it's irony) didn't you know `===` operator is faster than `==`?

Comment: Btw, can anyone please refer me on where in ES5.1 specification this behaviour with `use strict` is explained? Like when the code is `strict` then `thisBind` is `undefined`. Spent good 10 minutes there but no traces of it.

Comment: I don't understand the obsession about micro-optimzations either, so it's probably me who's at fault here. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected behaviour:

with `'use strict';` a function's context is `undefined`, not a global object.

Comment: Really? Didn't know that. 
My main problem is that the very same code works in google closure compiler.

Comment: @ThiagoMirandadeOliveira what is that "the very same code"?

Comment: Sorry for my english. But basically the same code on Google Closure Compiler works

Comment: For what's worth, I've noticed that the Google Closure Compiler strips out the 'use strict' from all files ( dunno why ). So that's why it worked with it.
Thanks for the help!